# Subset using column name defined using paste0 and a variable

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

I have a data.table like this:

```
dt <- data.table(asset=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5"),
                min_s1=c(.1,NA,NA,.1,NA),
                min_s2=c(NA,.5,.5,NA,NA),
                min_s3=c(.15,NA,NA,NA,.15))
```

I can manually subset on the NA values as follows which gives me the output I want:

```
empty1 <- dt[is.na(min_s1)]
empty2 <- dt[is.na(min_s2)]
empty3 <- dt[is.na(min_s3)]
```

But, what I really need to do is subset dynamically using the column name and also name the result incorporating the i variable in a loop.  The loop is important because this will ultimately be used in a parallel computing script.  I would like something like this (it doesn't work; just showing what I am looking for):

```
foreach (i in 1:3) %do% {
  empty(i) <- dt[is.na(min_s(i))]
}
```

I tried using the following as well as many of its variations to no avail:

```
paste0("empty",i) <- dt[is.na(paste0("min_s",i))]
```

Any ideas how I could accomplish this?
I use a Windows 7 pc.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just loop through the 'min' columns using `lapply` and subset the dataset

```
lapply(dt[,-1, with =FALSE], function(x) dt[is.na(x)])
#$min_s1
#   asset min_s1 min_s2 min_s3
#1:    x2     NA    0.5     NA
#2:    x3     NA    0.5     NA
#3:    x5     NA     NA   0.15

#$min_s2
#   asset min_s1 min_s2 min_s3
#1:    x1    0.1     NA   0.15
#2:    x4    0.1     NA     NA
#3:    x5     NA     NA   0.15

#$min_s3
#   asset min_s1 min_s2 min_s3
#1:    x2     NA    0.5     NA
#2:    x3     NA    0.5     NA
#3:    x4    0.1     NA     NA
```

Comment: This works perfectly and is very simple code.  Thanks for your help on this as well as your many other useful answers on which I have relied!

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've understood your question correctly, so try the following:

```
   dt <- data.table(asset=c("x1","x2","x3","x4","x5"),
                 min_s1=c(.1,NA,NA,.1,NA),
                 min_s2=c(NA,.5,.5,NA,NA),
                 min_s3=c(.15,NA,NA,NA,.15))

vec_store <- c()
empty <- list()
names <- names(dt)[!grepl("asset", names(dt))]


for(i in names){
  vec_store <- dt[is.na(dt[,get(i)])]
  empty[[paste0(i)]] <- vec_store
}
```

This gives you:

```
> empty
$min_s1
   asset min_s1 min_s2 min_s3
1:    x2     NA    0.5     NA
2:    x3     NA    0.5     NA
3:    x5     NA     NA   0.15

$min_s2
   asset min_s1 min_s2 min_s3
1:    x1    0.1     NA   0.15
2:    x4    0.1     NA     NA
3:    x5     NA     NA   0.15

$min_s3
   asset min_s1 min_s2 min_s3
1:    x2     NA    0.5     NA
2:    x3     NA    0.5     NA
3:    x4    0.1     NA     NA
```

In your code, you can't use `paste0(empty,i)` to create objects, I find the easiest way to do this is to create an empty vector, or data.table, then store it in a list. Once it is in the list you can do operations on the list, or pull it out of the list individually. That is why i created the `vec_store` an empty vector, and `empty` an empty list.

Hope that helps.

Comment: this works.  Thanks for the help.  Akrun's answer is a bit simpler with the same result.